# Finding Bounding Box from CLLocationCoordinate2D

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapkit, cllocation, mkcoordinateregion

I am working with an API that allows me to specify a "bounding box" of coordinate which allows me to only return results within that box:

- Returns a list of geocaches inside the specified bounding box sorted
  by the distance from the center of the box.
- The parameters south
  latitude, west longitude, north latitude, east longitude define the
  edges of a bounding box.
- Coordinates should be in decimal degrees Use
  positive numbers for north latitude and east longitude and negative
  numbers of south latitude and west longitude.
- The box cannot cross
  the 180° longitude line or the 90° or -90° points.

The math for this is a little beyond me, but I found somewhat helpful calculations, but I am not sure it is what I need for the API:

```
MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(self.mapView.centerCoordinate, 2000.0, 2000.0);
CLLocationCoordinate2D northWestCorner, southEastCorner;
northWestCorner.latitude  = center.latitude  - (region.span.latitudeDelta  / 2.0);
northWestCorner.longitude = center.longitude + (region.span.longitudeDelta / 2.0);
southEastCorner.latitude  = center.latitude  + (region.span.latitudeDelta  / 2.0);
southEastCorner.longitude = center.longitude - (region.span.longitudeDelta / 2.0);
```

Does anyone know how I could do this? Are the calculations here not helpful in order to get the `west longitude, north latitude, east longitude` that define the edges of the bounding box?

**EDIT:**

The error I am getting:

`Invalid value for parameter: bbox=south,west,north,east`

Using the center value:

`center=37.552821,-122.377413`

Converted Box (after calculations from above):

`bbox=37.561831,-122.388730,37.543811,-122.366096`

**Final Working code:**

```
// Current distance
MKMapRect mRect = mapView.visibleMapRect;
MKMapPoint eastMapPoint = MKMapPointMake(MKMapRectGetMinX(mRect), MKMapRectGetMidY(mRect));
MKMapPoint westMapPoint = MKMapPointMake(MKMapRectGetMaxX(mRect), MKMapRectGetMidY(mRect));
CLLocationDistance distance = MKMetersBetweenMapPoints(eastMapPoint, westMapPoint);

// Region
MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(request.center, distance, distance);
CLLocationCoordinate2D northWestCorner, southEastCorner;
northWestCorner.latitude  = request.center.latitude  + (region.span.latitudeDelta  / 2.0);
northWestCorner.longitude = request.center.longitude - (region.span.longitudeDelta / 2.0);
southEastCorner.latitude  = request.center.latitude  - (region.span.latitudeDelta  / 2.0);
southEastCorner.longitude = request.center.longitude + (region.span.longitudeDelta / 2.0);
base = [base stringByAppendingFormat:@"bbox=%f,%f,%f,%f&", southEastCorner.latitude,northWestCorner.longitude,northWestCorner.latitude,southEastCorner.longitude];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have gotten your hemispheres reversed. North and east are positive. So if you start from the center latitude and you want to find the northern boundary you ADD half the delta, not subtract.

Comment: So, you are saying I need to just reverse all my plus' to minus and visa versa?

Comment: Yeah, that will get you the correct `northWestCorner` and `southEastCorner`. Have you tried that yet?

Comment: Yeah, I tried fixing what you said, then using the string `base = [base stringByAppendingFormat:@"bbox=%f,%f,%f,%f&", northWestCorner.latitude,northWestCorner.longitude, southEastCorner.latitude,southEastCorner.longitude];` and it still gives me an error. Can you post the code you think it needs to be? I am not sure I am getting this correctly.

Comment: How about you post the error you're getting instead. Along with a print out of the values in your `region`. Edit the original question, there is not enough room in a comment box for what you need to show.

Comment: Your bounding box is upside down. See how it expects "south,west,north,east", but you are giving it north, west, south, east.

Comment: Ok, that fixed the error, which is a good thing, so at least it is working. But I get no results back. I am using `2000` for `latitudinalMeters` and `longitudinalMeters`. Is there a way to get the current map zoom level and turn that into meters so it can be used here? NEVERMIND. FIGURED THIS OUT.